# Classify irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $D_{6}$ up to isomorphism: guidance on part of method

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm taking a first course in representation theory and struggling a bit with this question:

> Classify the irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $D_{6}$ up to isomorphism.

$D_{2n} = \{ r, s: r^n = s^2 = e, srs = r^{-1} \}$ is the dihedral group with order $2n$.

**What I've done so far:**

Suppose $\rho$ is a representation. So $\rho(r)$ is some complex square matrix with at least one eigenvector $v$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since $\rho(r)^3=1$, $\lambda$ must satisfy $\lambda^n-1=0$.

I've also considered the space $W=\langle v, \rho(s) v \rangle$ and shown that it is $D_{6}$-invariant (consider $\rho(r) \rho(s) W$ and $\rho(s) \rho(s) W$ and use properties of the group elements and that $\rho$ is a homomorphism) which shows that $V=W$, i.e. $V$ is a degree $1$ or $2$ representation.

**Where I'd like guidance:**

So I assume that now I must iterate through all possible values of $\lambda$ and find all possible representations for each, right? That is, since $r$, $s$ generate the group and the representation's degree is at most $2$, find $1 \times 1$ or $2 \times 2$ matrices $A, B$ for $\rho(r)$ and $\rho(s)$ that obey the group structure and such that $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$?

How would I calculate this in practice? In the $2 \times 2$ case, it seems like a lot of hefty algebra to figure out the constraints for $ABA=B^{-1}$, $B^2=I$, $A^3=I$ and making sure $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$, if we were to just write, say,

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix}
e & f \\
g & h
\end{pmatrix}$$

and churn through mindless algebra. So there's got to be a better way, right? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is in general the most efficient method to do so, if there is one at all but in this case it is easy once you consider that $D_6$ is group of symmetries of triangle which you can also interpret as follows:

$r$ is the anticlockwise rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ by $120°$ and $s$ is reflection of $\mathbb R^2$ through $X$ axis(or $Y$, whichever you prefer but let's take $X$ axis here). Now you can easily see that matrix representation of $s$ will be

$s = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\
0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

And for $r$ you can use rotation matrix which for angle $\theta$ is

$\mathcal R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$

Hence

$r = \begin{pmatrix}\cos 120°&\sin 120°\\ \sin 120° &\cos 120°\end{pmatrix} = $ \begin{pmatrix}-1/2& -\sqrt{3}/2\\
\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2\end{pmatrix}$
$

That will give you the representation you want. You can check that it's irreducible.