# Method for classifying irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $D_{10}$ of dimension $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, dihedral-groups, irreducible-representation

$D_{2n} = \{ r, s: r^n = s^2 = e, srs = r^{-1} \}$ is the dihedral group with order $2n$.

I'm trying to classify the $2$-dimensional irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations of $D_{10}$ up to isomorphism. [This page on the subwiki Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups) says that there should be two such representations of the form

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(2 \pi k / 5) & -\sin(2 \pi k / 5) \\
\sin(2 \pi k / 5) & \cos(2 \pi k / 5)
\end{pmatrix}, s=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad k = 1,2$$

which intuitively makes sense considering $D_{10}$ as the symmetries of a pentagon.
However, I'm trying to derive this a priori with no knowledge of how many representations there are or what form they may be in. How do I derive a priori all possibilities for what $s$ could be, so I know that I have all the representations? I'd want to show that I've got all possibilities for $r$ and $s$, and then can work from there on showing there are two isomorphism classes.

I've asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788080/classify-irreducible-mathbbc-representations-of-d-6-up-to-isomorphism) and gotten an answer, I just don't understand how we can derive this and show there are no more possibilities.

Comment: Frobenius reciprocity so induced representation from the nontrivial irreps of the normal subgroup $\langle r\rangle$ of index 2...

Comment: @user10354138 I'm very new to rep theory, I haven't heard of Frobenius reciprocity before

Answer (score 0):

For $K$ a field if you have matrix representation

$\rho : G\to GL_n(K)$

then for any matrix $M\in GL_n(K)$

$\psi : G \to GL_n(K)$

given by $\psi(g) = M\rho(g)M^{-1}$ is also a representation which is said to be isomorphic to the earlier.

For a degree two representation suppose $s\to S$ and $r\to R$. Since $S^2 = I$ eigenvalues are $1$ and/or $-1$. If both eigenvalues of $S$ were $1$(or $-1$) then for some basis $S$ will be $I$(or $-I$). In this case $S$ commutes with $R$ $\implies$ $SRS = R = R^{-1}$ $\implies$ $R^2 \ I$ which together with $R^5 = I$ implies $R = I$ hence we are getting degree two reducible representation. Which means for getting irreducible representation two eigenvalues be $1$ and $-1$. Then for some basis of $K^2$ you can always have $S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$.

So no matter which degree $2$ representation you are having, you can have $S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ in both. Obviously the representation of $r$ will be different for different non-isomorphic representations. To find representations of $r$ you can once again use rotations, this time by $72°$ as we are working with $D_{10}$. Now let's denote this anticlockwise rotation by $R$ which in matrix form looks like

$R = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(2 \pi  / 5) & -\sin(2 \pi / 5) \\
\sin(2 \pi / 5) & \cos(2 \pi / 5)\end{pmatrix}$

Let's call

$ S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$

As before, one obvious representation will be $s \to S$ and $r \to R$. Another will be $s \to S$ and $r \to R^2$ which is to say that applying $r$ rotates $\mathbb R^2$ twice by $72°$ or equivalently by $144°$. To see that these two are non isomorphic suppose contrary they were isomorphic. Which means there is $P\in GL_2(K)$ such that $ S = PSP^{-1}$ and $R^2 = PRP^{-1}$. But you can check that these two equations are not compatible with $R^5 = S^2 = I$ and $SRS = R^{-1}$.

For knowing how many and what type of irreducible representations are there priori you need to know that if there are $r$ non-isomorphic irreducible representations of $G$ with degree $d_i$ then $d_1^2 +\ldots+d_r^2 = |G|$. Moreover $r$ is same as the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. For small groups using these results you know beforehand the number and degrees of irreducible representations. To actually find them is a difficult task in general. For groups defined by using some geometry that geometry itself provides a tool to find some of the representations. For other groups there are other numerous techniques. But I don't know if there is any full proof technique that always works.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I guess you are referring to the fact that both eigenvalues could be $-1$ which would imply $s$ is in the centre which is not true. Is there anything else?

Comment: I am not sure even if this above comment makes complete sense. What I know is that if both eigenvalues were $-1$ then that will be direct some of two degree $1$ representations. But I don't know how to put that in the answer in simple manner.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Can you tell me if there is still any hole.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am not confusing but the answer may seem so. I guess I should have written $s\to -I$ than $s= -I$. I hope that will finally make it appropriate.